# MongoDB similar array query

Tags: node.js, arrays, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

i have a project where i need to fetch a similar array from my mongoDB database. The array will look something like this:

```
["hi", "how", "are", "you"]
```

and in the database an entry will look like this:

```
{
"trigger": ["hi", "how", "are, "you", "doing"],
"response": "Hi, im fine"
}
```

and there's another document looking like this:

```
{
"trigger": ["who", "are", "you"],
"response": "I am a bot"
}
```

So, is there any way to fetch that document from the db just by similar entries and structure of the array.

Comment: Would you like the get the first one but not the second one?

Comment: I'd be tempted to implement a `"$function"` that scores the similarity using n-grams, Levenshtein, Damerau–Levenshtein, or some other linguistic distance metric and then `"$sort"`/`"$limit"` to select the best `"trigger"`/`"response"`.  Or is there a metric that could be derived from a `"$regex"`, or a series of `"$regex"`, based on the input array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
collection.find({trigger: {$in: inputArray}}, function(err, items){
    console.log(err, items);
});
```

Hope this helps!